# Error:maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison . Concatenar string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def metodo(lista):
    valor = 0
    for i in lista:
        if (i=="0") and (valor==" "):
            met(lista)
            break
        else:
            lista += " 1 7 0 98 75"
            metodo(lista)
            valor = i

def met(lista):
    valor = 0
    cont = 0
    seguir = True
    while seguir:
        for i in lista.split(" "):
            if (i=="0") and (valor==" "):
                print(cont)
                seguir = False
                break
            else:
                cont += 1
                valor = i

def main():
    lista = "3 67 453 23 12"
    metodo(lista)

main()
```

Quiero recorrer la 1º lista (string) entera y si no ha encontrado el 0, quiero que se concatene mas a la lista y volver a repetir el método y cuando encuentre el 0 pasar al otro método. Pero me da error y no me lo realiza, llevo varios días y no consigo resolverlo.

Comment: Por curiosidad, eres el mismo usuari@ que el de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/340188/15089, lo digo porque los códigos son muy similares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando vuelves a llamar la función siempre verifica la primera posicion de tu cadena llamada lista y por eso siempre entra en el else y le concatena->" 1 7 0 98 75" de forma infinita

```
def metodo(lista):
    print(lista)
    valor = ""
    c = 0
    for i in lista:
        if (i == "0") and ( valor == " "):
            met(lista)
            break
        else:
            c = c + 1
            valor = i

    if(c == len(lista)): # valida que el for anterior ya termino
        metodo(lista+" 1 7 0 98 75")

def met(lista):
    valor = 0
    cont = 0
    seguir = True
    while seguir:
        for i in lista.split(" "):
            if (i=="0"): #la otra condicion no se ocupa por que le aplicaste split a la cadena
                print(cont)
                seguir = False
                break
            else:
                cont += 1
                valor = i

def main():
    lista = "3 67 453 23 12"
    metodo(lista)

main()
```